# MS Edge continue past all breakpoints

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, javascript-debugger

How do you resume execution and skip *all* breakpoints in MS Edge? In Chrome you can click and hold on the "play" button (seen below) to resume execution and ignore breakpoints:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable all breakpoints in the F12 tools of Microsoft Edge by hitting Ctrl+Shift+F11.

Or, in the Debugger tab of F12, select the Breakpoints tab and click the "disable all breakpoints" button to achieve similar results.[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that option was there. In general, all the icons in the debugger are not very intuitive and don't seem to follow typical icon recognition standards. You have to hover over every one to understand what they do. Also, this solution requires me to re-enable breakpoints after I've resumed execution. A feature similar to Chrome's would be nice.